# JSON Parsing the same key for different values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

I'm doing a Json parsing, in that i need to parse the "TStatus" key to show the tables.

**In that TStatus key, the values are 3types. They are 100001, 100002, 100003.**

I want only 100001 values nothing else... How to get these values and store it in array.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [arrayOfoccupiedTables valueForKey:@"TStatus"];
```

The response is

```
 {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100003;
        "Table_Id" = 446;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 447;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 448;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 449;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 450;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 451;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 452;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100003;
        "Table_Id" = 453;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 454;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 455;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 456;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 457;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 458;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 459;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 460;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 461;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 462;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100003;
        "Table_Id" = 463;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 464;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 465;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 466;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 467;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 468;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 469;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 470;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 471;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 472;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 473;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 474;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 477;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 478;
    },
        {
        Msg = "";
        TStatus = 100001;
        "Table_Id" = 479;
    }
)
```

Plz help me out of this guys... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter array using **NSPredicate.**

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TStatus == 100001"];`

`NSArray *filtered  = ["Your Array" filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];`

in filtered array you get value where **Tstatus = 100001;**

Comment: NSMutableArray *array = [arrayOfoccupiedTables valueForKey:@"TStatus"];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TStatus == 100001"];
        
        NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        
        
        NSLog(@"Occupied tables are %@", filtered);
Its getting crash at filteredArrayUsingPredicate. The error is  [<__NSCFNumber 0x76f2370> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key TStatus.'

Comment: @Joker can you please tell me what kind of object you store in your NSArray?

Answer (score 1):

you have a Array of this all Data and for example array name is `arrList` then just use bellow code when you want to get whole data which TStatus is 100001 then filter with bellow code..

```
NSMutableArray *arrTStatus = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for (int i =0; i<[arrList count]; i++) 
 {
     if ([[[arrList objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"TStatus"] isEqualToString:@"100001"] ) 
     {
          [arrTStatus addObject:[arrList objectAtIndex:i]];   
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

```
[allObject filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TStatus = 100001"]];
```

Comment: [arrayOfoccupiedTables filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TStatus = 100001"]];
        

        
        NSLog(@"Occupied tables are %@", arrayOfoccupiedTables);
it is showing all the tstatus values in the log.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (NSDictionary *status in statuses) {

NSString *Tstatus = [status objectForKey:@"TStatus"]
if([Tstatus isEqualToString:@"100001"){
//Do your code here
}
}
```

Refer this [More about json](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c)